# How to change the constructor initialization value in c++ and explain the reason?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

```
using namespace std;


class Gparent{
    public:
    int house;
        Gparent(){
            house = 1;
            cout<<house<<endl;
        }
    ~Gparent(){
        cout<<"Gparent got killed"<<endl;
    }
};

class Parent: private Gparent{
    public:
        Parent(){
            Gparent::house=2;
            cout<<Gparent::house<<endl;
        }
    ~Parent(){
        cout<<"Parent got kiled"<<endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    Gparent g;
    g.house=100;
}
```

output:
1
Gparent got killed

why the output is not 100?
I can understand the object creation but bit confused with the initialization part.Could someone help me to understand the concept?

Comment: Not directly related, but nonetheless interesting for beginners: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766)

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote  `Gparent g;` this means

> you are defining an object of type `Gparent` using the **default constructor**.

Now you have already provided a default constructor as :

```
Gparent(){
            house = 1;
            cout<<house<<endl;
        }
```

So the data member `house` is **assigned** a value of `1` and then you print that value using `cout`. Which is why you get the output `1` **since** `house = 1` at this point.

**Next** when the object `g` is destroyed, the destructor is ran/executed and  you get the output `Gparent got killed`.

So you didn't get the output 100 **because** the variable `house` had a value of `1` at the time of using `cout`.

Note if you use `cout` **after** the statement `g.house = 100;` you will see that its value is changed to 100 and hence 100 is printed on the console.

```
    Gparent g;
    g.house=100;
    cout << g.house<<endl;//THIS PRINTS 100 now because house = 100 at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

See what your code compiles to [here](https://godbolt.org/z/P1fbv3o3Y). In the `main()`, this is what it *roughly* gets compiled to

```
call    Gparent::Gparent() [base object constructor]
:
mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 100
:
call    Gparent::~Gparent() [base object destructor]
```

It's basically just calling the `constructor`, so that'll print `1` since that's what `house` is initialized to and *only after that* the value of `g.house` is changed. And then the destructor is called so that'll print `Gparent got killed`. To see the changed value, you could perhaps change your code to

```
class Gparent{
    public:
    int house;
        Gparent(){
            house = 1;
            cout<<house<<endl;
        }
    ~Gparent(){
        cout<<house<<" Gparent got killed"<<endl;
    }
};
```

so that now the updated `house` member variable is printed during the destruction and you should get

```
1
100 Gparent got killed
```